# How to prevent form submission using GET method in JSF 2.0?

Tags: jsf-2

I am developing an JSF 2.0 application for IBM Webshere 7.0 and I want to prevent user submitting a form using the GET method for security reason i.e user will not be able to submit a form appending the form values to the Query String.

Is there any simple solution for this or I need to build filter to prevent this ?

Comment: Uh, this question is strange. How exactly did you submit a form by GET? This is already not possible with standard JSF `<h:form>`. Or were you assigned this task and you didn't even investigate/test/hack yourself at all before posting a question?

Comment: I did investigate and I was able to submit a form in the following way: www.myhost.com?fieldName1=Test&fieldName2=Test2 and values of those fields did come to the backing bean. This is what I want to prevent.

Comment: Then you've there some odd design. How about the action invocation? Such a bean is useless if nothing is been done with the data.

Comment: basically I have appended all the post parameters that is being sent to the application to the URL as I have mentined earlier (including JSFVIEW state) and it did call the action method :(.

Answer (score 0):

When you use JSF `<h:form>` it does a POST request be default. Even though a Query string is sent, since the submission method is POST, the result is not sent as a query string, that is, it is not added to the action URL of the form. Rather, the string is sent as the body of the HTTP request and the doPost() method of the FacesServlet will be invoked.

See also:

- [Proper way to call servlet from Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175963/proper-way-to-call-servlet-from-facelets/10176840#10176840)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string